# JavaScript answers

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
(function() {
    main();
    function main() { 
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'http://example.com/search.php',
                data: { value: '123' },
                cache: false,
                success: function(returndata) {
                    $('#widget').html(returndata);
                }
            });
        });
    }
})();
```

```html
<script src="http://example.com/widget.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="widget"></div>
```

When I paste widget on my site, it works perfectly and I get answers who is in div "widget" but if I paste this:

```
<script src="http://example.com/widget.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="widget"></div>
```

for another page it's not working. Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you have jquery on the other page? Can you check your console and print the error?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: You're probably experiencing Cross Site Restrictions. Could you please check your developer-console, and see if you recieve any errors?

Comment: @Jonas-m problem is with  Cross Site Restrictions  thx

Comment: why do you do this: `(function() {main(); function main() {JQuery(document).ready(function($){...});}})();` instead of this: `JQuery(function($){...});`

Answer (score 1):

As of your comment, you are experiencing Cross domain restrictions ([Same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)). A workable solution for this is to serve your content from "`search.php`" as `jsonp` instead.

```
<?php

header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
$searchResults= array("Article 1", "Article 2", "Article 3");
echo $_GET['callback'] . '('.json_encode($searchResults).')';

?>
```

In your jQuery `$.ajax`, you should set the `dataType`  to "`jsonp`, and perhaps set the parameter `crossDomain`  to `true` aswell.

```
(function() {
    main();
    function main() { 
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                crossDomain: true, // Shouldent be neccesary.
                url: 'http://example.com/search.php',
                data: { value: '123' },
                cache: false,
                success: function(returndata) {
                    $('#widget').html(returndata);
                }
            });
        });
    }
})();
```

Hope it works out for you.

Comment: thank you Jonas, my mistake. your script works but I have question how I can return html code?  example '<div id ="red"> <b> json_encode($searchResults) </b> </div>'

Comment: You will have to enter the HTML into the array, which is being converted to JSON.  $array = array("<div id='red'>".$searchResult."</div>");     json_encode($array);...   Please remember to accept the answer as correct. Thank you.

Comment: in search.php file I doing  query for mysql database, how I can  pass  value to  variable ?

Comment: When I assign const variable in search.php I get answers, but I want to retrieve the value of widget id, example: 
<div id="widget" data-value="myname"></div>